# How to correctly make a post request to yandex translete api through QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, api, qt

I decided to try Yandex translator in my project. The problem is [no examples](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/translate/operations/translate) of working with api in c++ or qt. Therefore, I decided to figure it out myself with the help of QNetworkAccessManager, after sitting all day, I realized that it was time to go here

```
QUrl url = QUrl("https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate");
QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onFinish(QNetworkReply*)));

QHttpMultiPart * http = new QHttpMultiPart(this);
QHttpPart receiptPart;
QJsonObject metaBody;

metaBody.insert("targetLanguageCode", "ru");
metaBody.insert("texts", "Hello");
metaBody.insert("folderId", "b1gdeb0pudkrac4ij1hd");

receiptPart.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
receiptPart.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer LjJrImZGOkZzMy4"); // key changed
receiptPart.setBody(QJsonDocument(metaBody).toJson());


http->append(receiptPart);
QNetworkReply * ans = mgr->post(QNetworkRequest(url), http);
```

I get into the `onFinish` method, but there is no data in `rep`, even about an error.

```
void myClass::onFinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QJsonParseError parseError;
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc;

    jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson( rep->readAll(), &parseError );

    QString str = rep->readAll();
    qDebug() <<str;
}
```

Although the key is not correct, the api gives the answer:

```
{
 code: 16
 "message": "Token signature mismatch, Key id: ajef3df54ebijh16f737",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
   "requestId": "c2bccede-0ba7-408e-bcdc-a13facf5c978"
  }
 ]
}
```

My account / key is in working order, checked with a Python example

Answer (score 0):

and so, the most important part of `QNetworkReply` should be removed after finished ,you didn't do it)

> Note: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the
> user to delete the QNetworkReply object at an appropriate time. Do not
> directly delete it inside the slot connected to finished(). You can
> use the deleteLater() function.

I propose to do so

```
void myClass::onFinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QJsonParseError parseError;
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc;

    if(!rep->isOpen())
       {
          qDebug() << "NetworkReply didn't open!!";
          rep->deleteLater();
          return;
       }
    QString str = rep->readAll();

    rep->close();
    rep->deleteLater();

    jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson( str, &parseError );
    qDebug() <<str;

}
```

and try to catch errors like this

```
....
QNetworkReply * ans = mgr->post(QNetworkRequest(url), http);

connect(ans , &QNetworkReply::errorOccurred,
        this, &MyClass::slotError);
connect(ans , &QNetworkReply::sslErrors,
        this, &MyClass::slotSslErrors);
```

I think this will help you to advanced forward)

[google translate example](https://github.com/GSam/Capture2Text/blob/master/Translate.cpp)

Comment: Thanks for trying but it didn't work